# How can I create a web service in Python that I can link to in Microsoft Access?

Tags: python, database, ms-access, networking

At my workplace, we use Microsoft Access to store and manipulate administrative data. We have two Microsoft Access database files: A 'front-end' (containing only forms and queries) and a 'back-end' (containing only tables). The 'front-end' uses the Linked Table Manager feature in Access to get data from and save data to the 'back-end'. The files are often linked across the LAN and even between sites.

I want to build a Python web service, hosted on an Apache web server, that effectively replaces the back-end file. I want to expose tabular data that can be consumed by the front-end. The front-end must have the ability to update data on the web server.

Does Microsoft Access have this feature? How is the data exposed by Python (XML?) Are there any gotchas to look for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853370/what-do-i-need-to-read-microsoft-access-databases-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

1. use Python to provide a Webservice (SOAP) as the new 'back-end'
2. rewrite the existing 'front-end' to consume it

You can implement 1. with [spyne](http://arskom.github.com/spyne/) and [consume it](http://metrix.fcny.org/wiki/display/tips/How+to+Create+a+Microsoft+Access+Client+for+a+SOAP-based+Web+Service+API) from Access. In Access 2012 there [is even an icon](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/accessdev/thread/5805cf08-97a6-4e17-b3a7-1649daeda829) for it

Comment: Thanks, that looks like just the thing I was after !

Comment: Hi, did you manage to create the web service that shows the tables?