# pyodbc to access.accdb : can't open access driver

Tags: ms-access, pyodbc

`6.3.1-arch1-1`

I have downloaded an access db `accdb` file and want to access it using pyodbc. I get this error

```
    conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

I've installed the following dependencies :

```
 # pacman -S unixodbc
 # pip install pyodbc
 # git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/msodbcsql.git
```

Here is the python script :

```
 import pyodbc
 
 conn_str = r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)};" +\
            r"DBQ=/home/stephen/shared/diet/access/CNF2015.accdb"
 
 conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

I have this configuration file

*~/.odbcinst.ini*

```
 [ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]
 Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
 Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.1.so.2.1
 UsageCount=1
```

Verify the driver path

```
 :> ls /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.1.so.2.1
  /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.1.so.2.1
```

Comment: Why does your pathing use forward slashes and lacks drive letter?

Comment: @June7 I'm running in Linux. That first line `6.3.1-arch1-1` is a reference to the OS.  Linux uses a different naming convention. Also there is no Access for Linux.

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853370/what-do-i-need-to-read-microsoft-access-databases-using-python

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25614063/2144390